# jquery and a value of a var

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wrote this code in jQuery, it's working perfectly, but I need the index value to begin at 1.

How can I do this?  This is my code:

```
$( "span.text" ).each(function( index ) {
    console.log( index + ": " + $( this ).attr('name') );
    var micaracter= $(this).attr('name');
    $( "span.lista a#caracter_" + index).append(micaracter);
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Then just do the native programming method, add one with the zero based index,

```
 $( "span.lista a#caracter_" + (index + 1)).append(micaracter);
```